# How can I prevent an Error Establishing Database Connection when installing WordPress Multisite Network?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, networking

I have installed wordpress in a subdirectory.  After I run the setup I get an Error Establishing Connection to Database when attempting to access my site.  If I comment out the line define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false); in wp-config.php, then it works but the network doesn't read as being set up.  What is it about this line that breaks my database connection?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this line. Are you sure you followed the exact installation steps? Check [this ebook](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/) and [this one](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-110/).

Comment: The problem was actually that the following line was missing:

define('MULTISITE', true);

File this one under operator error.  Thanks for the ebook links!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually that the following line was missing: define('MULTISITE', true); File this one under operator error.